# Unable To Ctrl-Drag From Table View Cell to Controller

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

I am learning about storyboards in iOS and I am having issues creating functions on cell presses in a Table View that is part of a tabbed view. I intend to share the view controller between the two tabs, and I have it working in the other tab, but when I try to ctrl-drag from the cell to the view controller I get nothing.

Is there something I have to do to hook the table view up to my view controller that does not happen automatically?

Answer (score 5):

You might not have given the objects in the storyboard the proper classes. You can do that in the identity inspector of the `UIViewControllers`. Then you can open up the dual inspector (two overlapping circles) and should be able to ctrl-drag from there.

Comment: While this something you should generally check. You should not be creating `@IBAction`s for prototype cells as they are actually used as a template to define reusable cells, especially when there are predefined methods to handle this situation. Not to mention that if you wanted to create `@IBActions` for a `UITableViewCell` I believe you would have to subclass it.

Answer (score 2):

If by "creating" functions do you mean "executing" functions. You should do this in code using the `UITableViewDelegate` method `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

Like So

```
extension <Your View Controller Class Name>: UITableViewDelegate {

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
     function()
  }

}
```

In addition, make sure that the `UITableView`'s `delegate` and `dataSource` properties are set to your view Controller class (`self`).